# C# REST Web Api POST object with arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, json, rest

I try to send to REST Api object with arrays something like this:

```
class MyObject
{
    public string Name{get; set;} 
    public IEnumerable<RelatedObject> Related{get; set;}
}
class RelatedObject
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

JSON format is this:

```
{
  "Name": "TestName",
  "Related": [{
  "Name": "TestNameRelated1"
  }{
  "Name": "TestNameRelated2"
  }]
}
```

There is method declaration

```
public void Post([FromBody]MyObject value) ...
```

Problem is that value is always null. I tried to change relation between MyObject and RelatedObject from 1:N to 1:1, I changed JSON string and I got value properly. 
I suppose problem is convert arrays? I tried to change IEnumerable to List but nothing happend and value was null.

How can I convert array into IEnumerable? How can I use own JSON Converter? I have this problem solved on client side but in server side serialization into object is build-in.

Thanks.

Comment: Try changing IEnumerable to IList and see

Comment: Issue is with ur json string..

Comment: I changed IEnumerable to List but value is still null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a valid json, there should be ',' between values in json array
try this

```
{
  "Name": "TestName",
  "Related": [{
  "Name": "TestNameRelated1"
  },{
  "Name": "TestNameRelated2"
  }]
}
```

Comment: What has changed?

Comment: @PatrickHofman OP is missing a `,` in the `Related` array

Comment: That would be quite useful information in an answer, don't you think? @suraj I hoped Amitay would understand the answer is quite unclear, basically just a code dump which is hardly useful.

Comment: I agree .. would have added it if I was the answerer :)

Comment: Thanks it works.